# Creating a number list with nested For loops in Python

Tags: python, loops, nested

I've been working on this now for well over four hours and i've tried to check several resources.

I'm trying to get something like this:

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

My current code for this is:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i, end = '')
    for j in range(10):
        print(j, end = '')
    print()
```

which prints this:

```
00123456789
10123456789
20123456789
30123456789
40123456789
50123456789
60123456789
70123456789
80123456789
90123456789
```

So I just need to get rid of the very most left-hand side. Additionally, I'm trying to produce something that looks like this:

0

0 1

0 1 2

0 1 2 3

0 1 2 3 4

0 1 2 3 4 5

0 1 2 3 4 5 6

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

And I can get it from this:

```
triangle = ''
n = 9
for i in range(0, n+1):
    triangle = triangle + (str(i))
    print(triangle)
print()


for i in range(11):
    for j in range(0+i):
        print(j,end=" ")
    print()
```

The problem with the first one is there isn't two for loops, one nested in the other. The problem with the second one is that I have range at 11 to get it to print to 9.

Lastly, I'm trying for this:

10

11 12

13 14 15

16 17 18 19

20 21 22 23 24

25 26 27 28 29 30

31 32 33 34 35 36 37

38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45

46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54

Which I've been getting with this:

```
x = 10 
for i in range (10):
    print (*range (x, x+i)) 
    x += i
```

But I need two for loops. I feel like I'm very close, but just can't get the finished product.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first instance, try this:

```
print('', end = '')
```

For the second instance, the mistake is that you are adding 0 to the second for loop. Change it to:

```
for j in range(0, 1+i):
```

The thing with `range` is that it goes until one number lower. Have a look at [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

For the last one, you can use the following code, where `y` starts at 10.

```
y = 10
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0, i):
        print(y + j, end=' ')
    print('')
    y += i
```

Comment: Thanks! I got an error when I attempted the last one so I ended up deleting the 'x += 1' and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with first code is that you are printing `i` , you do not need to print `i` . Code would be something like -

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        print(j, end = ' ')
    print()
```

For the rest of the question, if you are getting the answer without nested loops, why do you need nested loops?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to go about it -

First is very simple

```
ht = 10
y = range(ht)
"\n".join(map(lambda x: " ".join(map(str,x)), [y]*ht))
```

Second one is a bit interesting

```
ht = 10
y = range(ht)

for i in range(1, ht+1):
    print "  ".join(map(str, y[0:i]))
```

Third one

```
start = 10
ht = 9
limit = (ht*(ht+1))/2 # using the sum of n to find out total elements
y = range(start, limit+1)
for i in range(1, ht+1):
    print " ".join(map(str, y[0:i]))
    y =  y[i:]
```

The complicated `map(str, y)` is only to get a string to be printed.

Is this what you want?